# How to fix monitor text display to system text?

Tags: display, browser, fonts

I have a problem with my Acer K272HUL monitor (1440p) in that when connected to my laptop (Dell precision m3800 or Thinkpad T440s via mini DP) any text displayed outside of the native system (such as text on a webpage in Firefox or Chrome, but *not* Firefox Developer Edition) it becomes fuzzy and almost impossible to read for any amount of time. This is a recurring problem that I usually attribute to drivers, but I have had similar experiences too many times. The text appears perfectly clear and normal when attached to my desktop (R9 280). Is there any background information on this/similar experiences?

Sorry for not being able to explain this phenomenon correctly. If there's any other information I can provide or ways to improve this question format, please ask. Thanks.

Comment: If you screenshot it does the screenshot capture the behaviour you describe? Are you using hardware acceleration on the browsers?

Comment: In what resolution are you running the screen?